# Prefix for input line in a Java BufferedReader for a CLI

Tags: java, terminal, console, command-line-interface, bufferedreader

I have a standard Java BufferedReader to get input I put into the terminal.

```
System.out.println("This is my CLI, please enter a command"); 
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String input = new String(); 
input = reader.readLine();
```

now i would like to have some kind of prefix in the line that shows the user the program is still running and he can enter more commands.

So that it looks something like this:

```
This is my CLI, please enter a command 
myCLI> --help
```

Simular to the terminal that shows your current path before you enter a command.

Comment: Just use `System.out.print` to output that prefix

Comment: Well... that was too easy...